# Render points (spheres) at certain height (trees) in QGIS 3.0 3D View

Tags: qgis, point, 3d, qgis-3

I succesfully rendered 3D View of Vienna city centre as shown in [this tutorial by underdark](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/3d/) . I download trees point data in GeoJSON from OSM using Overpass API. Now I want to render the points as spheres that are elevated above the surface. However, I cannot find where in QGIS 3D Renderer settings can I define the height of the sphere. See screenshot provided.

I looked thru GIS Stack Exchange, Lutra Consulting webpage, Twitter feeds and other tutorials but I cannot find any answer. Anyone knows how to elevate the sphrere about ground?[image: QGIS 3.0 screenshot]

Comment: In your 3D Map, there's three icons. If you click the right-most ("Configure"), you can set the **elevation** of your spheres (if you have an elevation raster) or set the **vertical scale**.

Comment: @Joseph: "Configure" in the 3D View only works with raster data. As I said the trees are vector points from OSM.

Buildings (with height and extrusion) are set up in the Styling Dock --> 3D Renderer. I would expect it to be in the same place for points.

Comment: Anyone else have an idea? I am also having the same issues. Basically just want to view a point cloud in 3d using the height attributes. The 3D viewer only appears to support rasters....

Answer (score 1):

You could change the translation in Y to make the sphere float. The maximum value is 99.99 though.

Comment: The idea you suggested makes no difference for solving this issue.